# D3.js transition inside of transformation

Tags: javascript, d3.js, transition

I have some lines and I am moving them as a group. Is it possible to move them individually while that transformation is happening?

I made a small example with a stick man to show the case. He is supposed to move an arm while he is moving right. But the arm stays back.

http://jsfiddle.net/zre5ckk5/

```
var mode = "Transition";
        var bodySelection = d3.select("body");
        var divButton = bodySelection.append("div");
        var button = divButton.append("button")
            .attr("id","button")
            .text(mode);
        var svg = bodySelection.append("svg")
            .attr("width",800)
            .attr("height",600)
            .style("fill","red");   


        var chest = svg.append("line")
            .attr("x1",100)
            .attr("y1",100)
            .attr("x2",100)
            .attr("y2",50)
            .attr("stroke-width", 2)
            .attr("stroke", "black");       

        var legL = svg.append("line")
            .attr("x1",100)
            .attr("y1",100)
            .attr("x2",80)
            .attr("y2",130)
            .attr("stroke-width", 2)
            .attr("stroke", "black");

        var legR = svg.append("line")
            .attr("x1",100)
            .attr("y1",100)
            .attr("x2",120)
            .attr("y2",130)
            .attr("stroke-width", 2)
            .attr("stroke", "black");       

        var head = svg.append("circle")
            .attr("cx",100)
            .attr("cy",35)
            .attr("r",15)
            .attr("fill","black");

        var armL = svg.append("line")
            .attr("x1",100)
            .attr("y1",60)
            .attr("x2",80)
            .attr("y2",75)
            .attr("stroke-width", 2)
            .attr("stroke", "black")
            .on('click', function(){
        console.log('polyline click');
        console.log(this.getAttribute('x2'));            
  });       

        var armR = svg.append("line")
            .attr("x1",100)
            .attr("y1",60)
            .attr("x2",120)
            .attr("y2",75)
            .attr("stroke-width", 2)
            .attr("stroke", "black");

        var body = svg.selectAll("line,circle");


    button.on("click", function() {
        if(mode=="Transition")
        {
            moveBody(200);
            moveArmL();         
            mode="Reset";
        }
        else if(mode=="Reset")
        {
            moveBody(0);
            mode="Transition";
        }
        button.text(mode);
    })  

    function moveBody(x)
    {
        body.transition()
             .attr("transform", "translate(" + x + ",0)")
             .duration(1000);           
    }

    function moveArmL()
    {
        armL.transition()

             .attr("x2",90)
             .duration(500)
             .transition()
             .attr("x2",80)
             .duration(500);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To move the whole body elements together first add a group to the svg like below:

```
var svg = bodySelection.append("svg")
            .attr("width",800)
            .attr("height",600)
            .style("fill","red").append("g");
```

Now move the whole group

```
function moveBody(x)
    {
        svg.transition()
             .attr("transform", "translate(" + x + ",0)")
             .duration(1000);           
    }
```

Working code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/zre5ckk5/1/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer!

Comment: I tried to do a little change by leaving svg as it is and then adding:
var body = svg.append("g");
and then moving it with:
body.transition()
It doesn't work. Wouldn't it be the same as your example?

Comment: no its different...the circle and the line are added to the g group of the svg as in my example, the transform must happen on that. In your case you are adding a new g to the svg and that group has nothing in it(i mean the circle and line don't lie on it). So when the transform happen on that group you dont see anything moving.

Comment: I understand, you are right. I now created the body before the other elements, and then added the elements to the body. Now it works. I didn't want to move the svg directly because I wanted to add other things which don't have to move. Thanks a lot for the examples and explanations.